# Toggle button on table header works only after 2 toggles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I have a table with search functionality, where the input to search is opened in the table column headers when clicking the toggle button. When clicking the button again, it reverts back to column names. However, this functionality only works after two clicks, and thereafter introduces some weird styling which I have no idea where it is coming from.

Here is the javascript:

```
$('#action_btn').on('click', function (event) {

if (document.getElementById("toggle_id").value == "OFF") {

    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example thead th').each(function () {
        var title = $('#example tfoot th').eq($(this).index()).text();
        $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
        document.getElementById("toggle_id").value = "ON";
    });

    // DataTable
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    // Apply the search
    table.columns().eq(0).each(function (colIdx) {
        $('input', table.column(colIdx).header()).on('keyup change', function () {
            table.column(colIdx)
                .search(this.value)
                .draw();
        });
    });

} else {
    // Remove a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example thead th').each(function () {
        var title = $('#example tfoot th').eq($(this).index()).text();
        $(this).html('<th>'+title+'</th>');
        document.getElementById("toggle_id").value = "OFF";
    });
}
});
```

I have a fiddle to make it easier to view my code: http://jsfiddle.net/flldom001/vmxgz0s5/

How can I make sure that the button toggles the search in the following way?:
Default: off
Toggle: on/off

Comment: Can you list the issues together? Is it that the first time the toggle doesn't work or the styling or both? Check this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/aLd2tg7t/  Tried to fix the first time toggle issue.

Comment: Dude! Try from here.. at least the initial misfire is removed. Just replaced vanilla selectors with JQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/n8u02tfc/16/

Comment: Since, you are toggling it based on the value of "toggle_id", I just replaced the div with the hidden field, it worked for me. Change this line "<div id="toggle_id" value="OFF">" to "<input type="hidden" id="toggle_id" value="OFF">"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some changes in your Fiddle

I have removed the `#toggle_id` div outside the table and gave a `data-value` attribute.

Check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vmxgz0s5/7/)

```
$(document).on('click', '#action_btn', function (event) {

    if ($("#toggle_id").attr("data-value") == "OFF") {
        console.log($("#toggle_id").data("value"));
        // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
        $('#example thead th').each(function () {
            var title = $(this).text().replace('Search ', '');
            $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
            $("#toggle_id").attr("data-value", "ON");
        });

        // DataTable
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();

        // Apply the search
        table.columns().eq(0).each(function (colIdx) {
            $('input', table.column(colIdx).header()).on('keyup change', function () {
                table.column(colIdx)
                    .search(this.value)
                    .draw();
            });
        });

    } else {
        // Setup - remove a text input to each footer cell
        $('#example thead th').each(function () {
            var title = $(this).find('input').attr('placeholder');             
            $(this).removeAttr('class tabindex aria-controls rowspan colspan aria-sort aria-label style').html(title);
            $("#toggle_id").attr("data-value", "OFF");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This works fine, but why is the initial style of the table header different to the style that gets applied after toggling?

Comment: You are appending some input elements in the header. That's why the header changes, if I undestood correctly

Comment: Ah ok, is there a way for me to keep the initial state/style consistent with the post-toggling style?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using *value* attribute on div tags, work with *class* attribute. Toggle this attribute as needed.

As *value* is not a valid attribute for a div, it is not picked by the DOM. After you explicitly set the property *value* to 'ON' or 'OFF'. It picks that up.

Here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmxgz0s5/6/)

toggle_id element

```
<div id="toggle_id" class="OFF">
```

Jquery to check for on/off status

```
if ($("#toggle_id.OFF").length > 0) {
```